# Change the background color of Specific Row/Column in GridView windows 8?

Tags: gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How can we change background color of specific row or Specific column of a GridView. I tried to do this but it seems that we can not do this using xaml ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMO easyest way is make custom GridView class and override PrepareContainerForItemOverride method, and there you can make all sorts of customization for specific GridView item.

Here is the example :

http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/customizing-gridview-items-in-metro-app-4/

Another way is to use DataTemplateSelector and choose appropriate template for each item.